# PHP.ini and htaccess files missing 1.9 magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, .htaccess

Hi im creating a magento website for a tile company and having some problems with "memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted" when i try to create a configurable product it gives me front end errors and also in my error log the following:

```
[27-Nov-2014 14:49:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 953 bytes) in /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Model/Resource/Tag/Collection.php on line 25
```

So in attempt to fix it im trying to increase the amount of the memory limit and execution time in php.ini or in the htaccess file but both files are not there and werent from the start, all that i can find is php.ini.sample files im not sure whats going on or why but i cant do anything its causing a huge stoppage to my site id be grateful to anyone who can explain to me how to get around this i tried to just use the sample and create my own but it crashes the site and doesnt work until i remove the file again.

[image: File showing the error when creating a configurable product]

When i tried to recreate the PHP.ini file and htaccess file i get the following error:

```
There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1937085992
```

Im not sure what that means but the following error in the reporting is shown:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:78:"The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded";i:1;s:2522:"#0 /home/waxmancer/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(248): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2)
#1 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(165): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#2 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#4 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#5 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#6 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#7 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#8 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#9 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#10 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#11 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#12 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#13 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#14 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#15 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#16 /home/waxmancer/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/waxmancer/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}";s:3:"url";s:31:"/~waxmancer/index.php/?___SID=U";s:11:"script_name";s:21:"/~waxmancer/index.php";}
```

I fixed the error by adding the following code into my php.ini file

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

The site works now but when i click on any configurable product it just gives me a blank white page.

Still no luck

Comment: When are you getting this?

Comment: When i create a configurable product i will edit the original post with a screenshot of what it looks like

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your hosting company, you may or may not be able to change the settings via htaccess or your own custom php.ini file.

If your manual changes have crashed the site, or you get a 500 Error, you may not be able to override the memory_limit setting provided by your host. You should contact your hosting company if that is the case.

Either just re-download the magento version your using to grab the files, or i've pasted them below from the newest version (1.9.1):

**php.ini:**

```
; This file is for CGI/FastCGI installations.
; Try copying it to php5.ini, if it doesn't work

; adjust memory limit

memory_limit = 64M

max_execution_time = 18000

; disable magic quotes for php request vars

magic_quotes_gpc = off

; disable automatic session start
; before autoload was initialized

flag session.auto_start = off

; enable resulting html compression

zlib.output_compression = on

; disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

suhosin.session.cryptua = off

; turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = off

; PHP for some reason ignores this setting in system php.ini 
; and disables mcrypt if this line is missing in local php.ini

extension=mcrypt.so

; Disable PHP errors, notices and warnings output in production mode to prevent exposing sensitive information.

display_errors = Off
```

**.htaccess:**

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 512M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Comment: Ive tried this in the past when i do this i get the following error:


"There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1937085992"

Comment: Ok, so it's not a direct server error, but an internal magento one. What is the trace in that error log? (you can find the log file in var/report/1937085992) - open with any text editor

Comment: would you like me to edit the original with the error or post it here?

Comment: edit your original post, please =)

Comment: Done and thank you for the prompt response ive copied everything in there.